# Weird node placement of dot graph

Tags: graphviz, dot

I have the following source code for a graph in dot:

```
digraph name {
    rankdir="LR";
    node [shape="record"];
    1 [label="OUTPUT"];
    A [label="FWD|<i>i|<r_in>r_in|<r_out>r_out|<o>o"];
    B [label="FIFO|<r_in>r_in|<o>o"];
    C [label="Cons|<i>i|<r_out>r_out|<o>o"];

    A:o:e -> C:i:w;
    C:r_out:w -> A:r_in:e;
    B:o:e -> A:i:w;
    C:o:e -> 1:w;
    A:r_out:w -> B:r_in:e;
}
```

It consists of 4 nodes, which essentially could be placed one after another, in the order B -> A -> C -> OUTPUT. If dot would place the nodes in this order, only few edge would cross between two nodes.

However, calling dot like this:

```
dot mygraph.dot -Tpng -o mygraph.png
```

creates the following mess:

[image]

Edit: It seems, the order of the nodes in the source is important. However, as the source is generated from a program, outputting its internal signal flow structure, I cannot rely on it to put the nodes in the right order. I thought, dot and its graph layout engine can figure out on its own, which nodes are the first ones, such that the wires do not cross.

Answer (score 0):

Just define the nodes in the desired order:

```
digraph name {
    rankdir="LR";
    node [shape="record"];

    B [label="FIFO|<r_in>r_in|<o>o"];
    A [label="FWD|<i>i|<r_in>r_in|<r_out>r_out|<o>o"];
    C [label="Cons|<i>i|<r_out>r_out|<o>o"];
    1 [label="OUTPUT"];

    A:o:e -> C:i:w;
    C:r_out:w -> A:r_in:e;
    B:o:e -> A:i:w;
    C:o:e -> 1:w;
    A:r_out:w -> B:r_in:e;
}
```

yields

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your hint! However, the graph source is generated automatically from a program which just outputs its internal structure. It cannot really know, which nodes to put first, and which second. I thought, dot can figure this out on its own?

Comment: No it can't. The order in which they are defined determines the placement of the nodes. You will need to to find a way to adjust the output you are getting...